# New Wavefront obj importer - Split by Object?

Tags: import, obj

Using Blender 3.3.0, the new importer for Wavefront obj is no longer experimental, the python addon is marked legacy. There is already a proposal to completely remove the python version a couple of blender versions down.

While the new importer genereally works like a charm, there is something I'm missing that's very useful for how I use Blender at work.

The python addon has an option to split geometry by object and/or groups - into individual objects.
The new importer only allows to create vertex groups within the imported object.

With the python addon I am able to work with the files my clients provide me with (usually something like .step files), as with the split objects I can handle the individual parts of the device.
With vertex groups... I can not.

Is there a way to split an object by vertex groups? At once? Depending on object having to individually select vertex groups and separate them one by one is far too time consuming.
Also splitting the object by loose parts is also not an option, as objects/vertex groups consist of different unconnected parts.

Alternatively what would be the best way to raise awareness, so that the new importer might get the option to split into objects?

I am fully aware that I could just stop upgrading Blender as soon as the legacy addon will no longer be available. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a work-arounds:

1. Keep an older Blender version at hand merely for the import process can be an option. Import -> Save, continue in new Blender...
2. Using the old script (as long as it works, maybe under a different name).